# .htaccess to redirect all pages from domain to directory on same domain except root, /index.html, /index.php

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

I've searched and tried everything I've found and nothing seems to work quite right. What I'm trying to do is:

- redirect all pages from a domain (domain.com) to a directory within
  the same domain (domain.com/dir or domain.com/dir/index.php);

However, I do not want to redirect:

- domain.com/index.php;
- domain.com;
- www.domain.com
- and, obviously the directory to which all the pages will redirect to (domain.com/dir).

I'd like to use .htaccess to do this since it seems to be the most obvious choice–I'm just not as familiar with .htaccess scripting as I would like to be. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First off, [don't use `.htaccess`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when):

> in general, use of .htaccess files should be avoided when possible. Any configuration that you would consider putting in a .htaccess file, can just as effectively be made in a  section in your main server configuration file.

Put this in your `<VirtualHost>`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^(/|/index\..+|/dir/.*)$ /dir%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Or, if you insist on using `.htaccess` even after reviewing the Apache documentation on the matter, then you'll need to strip the leading slash from the match and replace strings:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^(|index\..+|dir/.*)$ dir%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```